# 18.04 Drivers for 16.04

Tags: drivers

I am having some trouble with my trackpad on Ubuntu 16.04, but it works fine on 18.04. I was wondering if there is a way to "import" drivers. I prefer 16.04 and it runs on my machine better than 18.04. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 'drivers' are really kernel modules. One suggestion would be to find what kernel.module in 18.04 is doing what you like with your trackpad, and ensure its installed & running on your 16.04 system. Many modules exist for many kernels, but I'd not suggest trying to load a 18.04 kernel module into a 16.04 kernel. However a better solution may be using your 16.04 with HWE kernels (hardware enablement stack), which lets 16.04 uses later kernels (inc. 18.04) I suspect may be what your answer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack & https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack

Comment: Linux's hardware driver policy is unrealistic and hindering. Waiting for dislikes from fellow members of the community...